# Why does my PHP Session check function fail with Wordpress... once?

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a simple session validator function for my site, which redirects to the login page if a specific session variable is not set.

```
public function checkSessionIsActive($session) 
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION["userID"])) {
        header('Location: https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

This works as expected throughout my site.

Recently I have added a Wordpress section to my main site. The Wordpress section sits in it's own directory, /knowledgebase.

I want to add the session validating function to the Wordpress side of the site, and have done so by adding it to the `index.php` page within `/knowledgebase` (the first page loaded when navigating to www.mysite.com/knowledgebase. I have ensured there is a `session_start()` too.

```
<?php
session_start();

require "../classes/pageHandler.class.php";

$page = new PageHandler;
$page->checkSessionIsActive($_SESSION);
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

For some reason, this does not work as expected. When navigating to www.mysite.com/knowledgebase, I am redirected as if `if (!isset($session["userID"]))` returns false.

I log back in, try the link again- it works. Every time, across all browsers.

To add to the strange nature of this issue, everytime I have tried a `var_dump($_SESSION)` on the /knowledgebase/index.php file and it shows the session variable "userID" is there and I am not redirected. Remove the var_dump, clear browsing history and try again- it fails first, then works second time around.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Answered for anyone else having this issue. Wordpress handles PHP sessions differently, and this is well documented online. A good article I found was https://www.ironistic.com/using-php-sessions-in-wordpress/ which helped solve this issue.